# Is it possible to have a variadic function in C with no non-variadic parameter?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have the following function:

```
void doStuff(int unusedParameter, ...)
{
    va_list params;
    va_start(params, unusedParameter);
    /* ... */
    va_end(params);
}
```

As part of a refactor, I'd like to remove the unused parameter without otherwise changing the implementation of the function. As far as I can tell, it's impossible to use `va_start` when you don't have a last non-variadic parameter to refer to. Is there any way around this?

Background: It is in fact a C++ program, so I could use some operator-overloading magic as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436968/variadic-function-without-specified-first-parameter), but I was hoping not to have to change the interface at this point.

The existing function does its work by requiring that the variable argument list be null-terminated, and scanning for the NULL, therefore it doesn't need a leading argument to tell it how many arguments it has.

In response to comments: I don't *have* to remove the unused parameter, but I'd do it if there were a clean way to do so. I was hoping there'd be something simple I'd missed.

Comment: look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436968/variadic-function-without-specified-first-parameter

Comment: @Axarydax: He specifically asks if there is another solution.

Comment: do you really have to remove it? You can treat it as the 1st variadic parameter.

Comment: @Nick D: You should make your comment an answer, you'd get at least one upvote from me.

Comment: "scanning for the NULL" - and you say you *don't* want to change the interface? For instance, to pass a pointer to an array ;-)

Comment: Of course, I'll change the interface entirely in due course. I find refactoring works best as a bunch of small testable steps (in this case, turning a non-member function into a member function) rather than trying to rewrite the code all at once.

Comment: Another [good example to make what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647983/7104681).

Comment: Another [good example to make what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199332/7104681)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice is either leave it as it is and use `va_list`, alias it (if it's GCC) as others pointed out, or do something along the lines of `exec(2)` interface - passing an array of pointers requiring a `NULL` terminator:

```
/* \param args  NULL-terminated array of
 *              pointers to arguments.
 */
void doStuff( void* args[] );
```

Either way it would be much better to refactor the interface to somehow take advantage of the type system - maybe overload on exact argument types used:

```
void doStuff( int );
void doStuff( const std::string& );
void doStuff( const MyFancyAppClass& );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is true, but invalid, the question here is for C and not C++, you can't overload function in C and creating an array can be costly. The answer below if much better.

Comment: From the OP: "... It is in fact a C++ program, ..."

Answer (score 16):

In GCC, you have a workaround: You can define a macro with a variable number of arguments and then add the dummy parameter in the expansion:

```
#define doStuff(...) realDoStuff(0, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Link to docs on variadic macros is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html +1, you beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` is a part of C99 standard of C language. So, it is not really "in GCC" but rather "in modern C" :)

Comment: Also supported in VC++ 2005 and later, even though that does not support C99.