# Common lisp: How many argument can a function take?

Tags: common-lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Lisp, how many inputs can the + function actually have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974080/in-lisp-how-many-inputs-can-the-function-actually-have)

The following code gives a "too many argument" error:

```
(setf u (loop for i upto 50000 collect 1))
(apply #'+ u)
```

similarly for

```
(apply #'= u)
```

So I guess when writing defun with &rest there is an upper bound for the number of arguments. What is it? I searched and tried [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node124.html#SECTION001630000000000000000) and various pages on that site but I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: A language specification is not an implementation. Ideally there would be "no limit", but implementations (and hardware limits) ..

Comment: I see. So it depends on implementation. I just wanted to know whether the language set an lower bound on this. I tried out `(defun crazy(n)
  (apply #'+ (loop for i upto n collect 1)))` in CLisp and Clozure CL, it is 4095 and 65535 respectively.

Comment: well you can expect any implementation to take at least 3 arguments, you probably want an upper bound for that lower bound now, don't you? :-)

Comment: Yeah, i wanted a lower bound of max. And now I found the answer is given by CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a constant called CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT that gives you the upper bound of how many arguments you can pass to a function.

However, in your initial example, you can definitely use REDUCE:

```
(reduce #'+ u)
```