# Ignore non-number values in a list and find the sum recursive method

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, mixed

I need to create a recursive method in LISP that takes the numbers in a list and finds the sum. Anything in the list that is not a number is skipped (For example, if the list contains "Cheese 12 Dog 8 Shoe 5", the output would be 25).

Right now my code finds the sum, but throws an error if there is anything in the list that is not a number. What can be changed to fix that?

```
(defun adder (lis)
   (cond
    ((null lis) 0)
    (t (eval (cons '+ lis)) )
  )
)
```

Comment: `numberp` determines whether an item is a number...  Something like `...(cons '+ (map 'list #'(lambda (x) (if (numberp x) x 0)) lis))`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

```
(defun adder (lis)
  (if (null lis)
    0
    (let ((c (car lis)))
      (if (numberp c)
        (+ c (adder (cdr lis)))
        (adder (cdr lis))))))
```

Your version is not recursive (you don't call adder inside of adder), maybe you meant something like this (which is non-recursive)?

```
(defun adder (lis)
  (apply '+ (remove-if-not 'numberp lis)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` on lists that can be long is a bit dangerous.  If the list is longer than [`call-arguments-limit`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm), then `(apply '+ list)` won't work.  Now, `call-arguments-limit` is typically pretty big in modern Lisps, but it's allowed to be as small as 50. For more information about this, see:

- [Common lisp: How many argument can a function take?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11753981/1281433) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11756063/1281433) uses `(reduce '+ …)`)
- [In Lisp, how many inputs can the + function actually have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9974080/1281433)

I think your best bet would be to use `reduce '+ list` with a key function that takes each number to itself and each non-number to `0`.  (This key function is what [abiessu mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936840/ignore-non-number-values-in-a-list-and-find-the-sum-recursive-method/19937184#comment29669332_19936840).)

```
(reduce '+ list :key (lambda (x) (if (numberp x) x 0)))
```

```
CL-USER> (let ((list '(cheese 12 dog 8 shoe 5)))
           (reduce '+ list :key (lambda (x) (if (numberp x) x 0))))
25
CL-USER> (let ((list '()))
           (reduce '+ list :key (lambda (x) (if (numberp x) x 0))))
0
```

Instead of using a more complex key function, you could also use `(remove-if-not 'numberp list)` to get rid of the non-numbers (or `(remove-if (complement 'numberp) list)`):

```
CL-USER> (let ((list '(cheese 12 dog 8 shoe 5)))
           (reduce '+ (remove-if-not 'numberp list)))
25
CL-USER> (let ((list '()))
           (reduce '+ (remove-if-not 'numberp list)))
0
```

Comment: I had forgotten the simpler ways of writing the `reduce` and `remove-*` operations, thanks for the reminder. :-)

Comment: @abiessu Well, I do think that this way is simpler, but more importantly, it's _safer_, because if your list is longer than [`call-arguments-limit`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm) then `(apply '+ list)` won't work, where as `(reduce '+ list)` is still OK.