# to apply #' or not to apply #'

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've just started to play around with Lisp (Common-Lisp), here's a function that calculates the average of a list of numbers

```
CL-USER> (defun average (list) (/ (apply #'+ list) (length list)))
AVERAGE
CL-USER> (average '(1 2 3 4))
5/2
```

however if I rewrite the function like so

```
CL-USER> (defun average (list) (/ (+ list) (length list)))
```

it doesn't work since (+ '(list-of-numbers)) can't be evaluated, hence the arguement of length and the expression in the + are incompatible.

is there a way of cajoling (list) to be evaluated naturally as an expression by + and passed as data to length ? rather than using apply #'

I've tried this:

```
(defun average (list) (/ (+ list) (length '(list))))
```

but this doesn't seem to do it either !

Comment: Is there a practical reason you want to be able to do this? I think your problem is the notion that the syntax (function (arg1 arg2)) is somehow more "natural" than (function arg1 arg2).

Comment: no reason, I'm just trying to understand ! Again no, (function arg1 arg2) seems the more "natural" (highly subjective ! admittedly), it just seems to me that it would be more "natural" to operate on how the args are seen by the function rather than "over riding" the function (with sharp-quote) to fit the args. If you see what I mean. Since quote(list) bypasses the default evaluation rule I was just wondering if there was some "inverse" of the quote that I'd missed somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

See [Common lisp: How many argument can a function take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753981/common-lisp-how-many-argument-can-a-function-take)

It would be preferable to use `(reduce #'+ list)` instead `(apply #'+ list)` because `apply` is subject to the limit of number of argument a that function can take.

So your average function should looks like:

```
(defun average (list)
  (/ (reduce #'+ list)
     (length list)))
```

BTW, the code `(length '(list))` returns 1 because it returns the lenght of a list containing the **symbol** "list".

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason not to use `APPLY` or, better, `REDUCE`. Here `REDUCE` is the correct function.

If you program in Lisp, most of the time you have to use a symbol, naming your operation, followed by arguments. This is the general basic expression style in Lisp. You might expect that there are shorter ways to write something like reducing a list with a function. But there isn't, in basic Lisp.

`(+ (list 1 2 3 4))` is an error because `+` expects numbers, not a list.

If you want to sum all numbers in a list, you have to use `REDUCE`. This operation is also known as *folding*.

Summing the numbers in a list:

```
(reduce #'+ (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Another simple way is to use `LOOP`:

```
(loop for n in (list 1 2 3 4) sum n)
```

Writing something like `(length '(list))` makes no sense, since you are *quoting* a list. A quoted list is treated as data and not code. Since it is constant data, the result is always `1`.

One of the Lisp ways to get to short programs is to build up a *vocabulary* of reusable functions. One doesn't use the shortest notation, but instead one is creating reusable functions with obvious names. Thus, if we *sum* a lot, we write a `sum` function:

```
(defun sum (list)
  (reduce #'+ list))
```

Then `average` is:

```
(defun average (list)
  (/ (sum list) (length list)))
```