# Calling a lambda function in a loop from a variable defined with `with`

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following lisp code

```
(defun sum (vec)
  "Summiert alle Elemente eines Vektors."
  (apply '+ vec))

(defun square (item)
  "Hilfsfunktion zum Quadrieren eines Elements."
  (* item item))

(defun calcVarianz (vec)
  "Berechnet die Varianz eines Vektors."
  (loop with len = (length vec)
        with mean = (/ (sum vec) len)
        with some_func = (lambda (x) (* x x))
        ; causes the error
        for item in vec
        collecting (square (- item mean)) into squared
        collecting (some_func item) into some_vector
        ; some_func cannot be found
        finally (return (/ (sum squared) (- len 1)))))
```

which works great (calculates the variance of a vector, that is).
Now, I was wondering if one could define the `sum` and the `square` functions as lambda within the `loop` construct but got stuck along the way. Is this possible with e.g.

```
with sum = (lambda (x) ...)
```

Got the error

```
The function COMMON-LISP-USER::SOME_FUNC is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why didn't you post what the "several errors" were?  Why didn't you show the actual code that produced these errors?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Added the error, thanks.

Comment: You could replace the use of `some_func` with the actual `lambda` expression, avoiding the need for `some_func` at all.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Haven't thought about it but you're right. I'll end up using this. However, for my learning purpose: why can't I name a lambda and use it afterwards?

Comment: Would this work?  `collecting (apply some_func (list item)) into some_vector`

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yep, that worked. Formulate an answer and I'm going to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: It bugs me that you're calling lists vectors.

Comment: I'd also use `(reduce #'+ your-list)` to sum a list (also works on vectors) instead of `apply`, fwiw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need funcall in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729549/why-do-we-need-funcall-in-lisp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply`, replacing

```
collecting (some_func item) into some_vector
```

with

```
collecting (apply some_func (list item)) into some_vector
```

Comment: In this case, you should use `funcall` rather than `apply`, as you already know what the arguments are, and they are not given to you as a list in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

If you bind a symbol to a function you need to use `funcall` or `apply` when attempting to call the function using the symbol:

```lisp
collecting (funcall some_func item) into some_vector
```

This is because ordinarily the *value* slot is bound when binding a symbol, and in this case the value slot is bound with the value of the function. When a symbol is encountered as the first element of a cons the *function* slot is checked for the function, and this is a different namespace. This is why `funcall` (or `apply`) is needed.

You can call `funcall` on a function object or on a symbol in the global environment. If a symbol is passed to `funcall` it is coerced to a function; this symbol must be in the global environment to avoid undefined behavior.

In this particular case the local variable `some_func` is bound to the function object specified by the `lambda` expression. Since `funcall` is itself a function it evaluates its arguments, so `some_func` evaluates to its value, which is a function object. This function object is then passed to `funcall` along with the value of `item`.

Contrast this with the OP code `(some_func item)`. This form is evaluated by first attempting to find a global function binding for `some_func`, but there is none to be found since `some_func` is a local variable. As a result of this an error is issued:

```
The function COMMON-LISP-USER::SOME_FUNC is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

Comment: Good explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define local functions, then you need FLET or LABELS. LOOP does not let us define local named functions. One can define variables in LOOP, bind them to a function object and call that with FUNCALL, though.

Here is an example for FLET and for LAMBDA&FUNCALL:

```
(defun varianz (list)
  "Berechnet die Varianz einer Liste von Werten."
  (flet ((sum (list)
           "Summiert alle Elemente."
           (reduce #'+ list))
         (square (item)
           "Hilfsfunktion zum Quadrieren eines Elements."
           (* item item)))           
    (loop with len = (length list)
          with mean = (/ (sum list) len)
          with some-func = (lambda (x) (* x x))
          for item in list
          collecting (square (- item mean)) into squared
          collecting (funcall some-func item) into some-list
          finally (return (/ (sum squared) (- len 1))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The others said everything what had to be said.

But back to the lambda functions - in this case the better style would be to give the functions names (for re-usability later in the script - or for your arsenal of utility functions - so for your own re-use).

```
(defun sum (lst)
  (reduce #'+ lst))

(defun mean (lst)
  (/ (sum lst) (length lst)))

(defun square (x)
  (* x x))

(defun squared-deltas (lst)
  (let ((x-mean (mean lst)))
    (mapcar (lambda (x) (square (- x x-mean)))
            lst)))

(defun variance (lst)
  (/ (sum (squared-deltas lst))
     (1- (length lst))))
```

`mapcar` instead of `loop` makes the code more concise.

`(reduce #'+ lst)` is to be preferred over `(apply #'+ lst)` in case `lst` contains more than 50 items.
See [In Lisp, how many inputs can the + function actually have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974080/in-lisp-how-many-inputs-can-the-function-actually-have)
.

## Lisp-Stat

The even better style would be to use a package, e.g. Lisp-Stat
https://lisp-stat.dev/docs/manuals/
.
It handles sequences of different data structures (lisp, vector, array, etc.) by using generic functions.

```
(ql:quickload :lisp-stat)

(lisp-stat:sum '(1 2 3))
(lisp-stat:mean '(1 2 3))
(lisp-stat:variance '(1 2 3))
```