# number of passed arguments in a va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions

All,

I want to control `the number of passed parameters` in a va_list.

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, fmts);
        vfprintf(stdout, fmts, args);
va_end(args);
```

Is there any possibility to get the number of parameters  just after a `va_start`?

Comment: No, as far as I know. Just pass in the number as first argument.

Comment: You have to count it for yourself.
Or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421681/how-to-count-the-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-function-that-accepts-a-variabl).

Comment: *You can't handle the number of arguments.*

Comment: You can't but you could use a macro. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you can use this macro to count params

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define NARGS_SEQ(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define fn(...) fn(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__) - 1, __VA_ARGS__)

static void (fn)(int n, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    printf("%d params received\n", n);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    fn("%s %d %f\n", "Hello", 7, 5.1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not count them directly.

For example `printf` is a variable count function which uses its first parameter to count the following arguments:

```
printf("%s %i %d", ...);
```

Function `printf` first parses its first argument (`"%s %i %d"`) and then estimates there are 3 more arguments.

In your case, you have to parse `fmts` ans extract `%`-specifiers then estimate other arguments. Actually each `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier` could count as an argument. [read more...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Exactly, what i want to do is to make my function (like printf more secure), For instance, if we have a printf(%s%s) and we pass only one parameter we will have a probleme because the second %s does'nt match any arguments so we will find in the output bizzard caracters...

Comment: You can not avoid those mistakes, `printf` itself cannot force the caller to pass arguments as same as specifiers.

Comment: For example you can write `printf("%i%i", 12);` it's wrong but possible

Comment: The best thing for the OP to do in this case would be to check the compiler documentation for possibilities to check arguments against format strings, which is possible with some sort of attributes in MSVC, C for AIX and DEC(/HP/Compaq) C.