# Can I know how many arguments my function gets?

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Given a function in c++, is there any way to get the number of arguments that my function requires? (like `argc` in `main` in c language).

For example:

```
double MyFunction(int x , int y) {   
    int NumOfParam= //.... =2;  
}
```

---

Why would this be useful to me?
For example, I want to write a function that inserts all the parameters of the function into a `vector`, and I thought doing it with a `for loop` that iterates through the arguments.

For example:

```
void MyFunction(int x,int y , int z){  
    std::vector<int> params;  
    for(int i=0; i< ?? ; i++) {  
        params.push_back("ArrayOfMyArguments[i]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of arguments passed to a function that accepts a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421681/how-to-count-the-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-function-that-accepts-a-variabl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is a function-template in conjunction with [variadic templates (a/k/a parameter packs)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template<class ... Args>
void f(Args ... args)
{
    std::cout << sizeof...(args) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    f(0, 1, 2); // prints 3
    f(0, 1, 2, 3, 4); // prints 5
}
```

This is generally not what you would use by default. Consider using ranges:

```
template<class Iterator>
void f(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    std::cout << std::distance(begin, end) << "\n";
}
```

which is more idiomatic.

Comment: Note that parameter pack is c++11 construct.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès question is tagged c++11 ;)

Comment: For sure, but such question let me though that OP isn't very aware about all of this. But you're right.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you come from a JavaScript background, where all functions have an `arguments` array. C++ is not JavaScript, and it's not possible.

If you want to have a dynamic number of arguments then the solutions are either:

- [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)
- [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)
- Using iterator pairs if you have a sequence from another container
- C-style [variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (where you need a special argument to tell you the number of variadic arguments, or an "end of argument" marker)
- Or an `argc` and `argv` like solution

If all you want to do is to populate a vector, then I rather recommend that you simply populate it directly, either through a loop when and where needed, or through the constructor taking an `std::initializer_list` (as explained in one of my comments).

If you really need to pass a variable number of arguments to a function, then I recommend parameter packs.

Comment: Or a `Iterator first, Iterator last` pair

Comment: This is more or less, all in one answer.