# Is it possible to create a C varargs function with no arguments?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a variadic function in C with no non-variadic parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622147/is-it-possible-to-have-a-variadic-function-in-c-with-no-non-variadic-parameter)

Is it possible to create a C varargs function with no arguments?

For example:

```
int foo(...);
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
list* create_list(...){
    list *mylist = list_create();
    void *current_arg = va_arg(void*);
    while (current_arg != NULL){
        list_add(mylist, current_arg);
        current_arg = va_arg(void*);
    }
    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: There is already a valid answer concerning functions. In the contrast to that, vaarg *macros* with only `...` are allowed. So if you'd tell us what you want to achieve, there might be a way ...

Comment: You can fake it with a dummy argument and a variadic macro that hides the need for the dummy argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Variadic functions must have one or more named parameters.

Try it yourself, you'll see something like:

> error: ISO C requires a named argument before '...'