# Differences in the initialization of the EAX register when calling a function in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86-64

There is a curious difference between assemblies of a small program, when compiled as a C-program or as a C++-program (for Linux x86-64).

The code in question:

```
int fun();
int main(){
    return fun();
}
```

Compiling it as a C-program (with `gcc -O2`) yields:

```
main:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp fun
```

But compiling it as a C++-program (with `g++ -02`) yields:

```
main:
    jmp _Z3funv
```

I find it puzzling, that the C-version initializes the return value of the main-function with `0` (`xorl    %eax, %eax`).

Which feature of the C-language is responsible for this necessity?

**Edit:** It is true that, for `int fun(void);` the is no initialization of the eax-register.

If there is no prototype of `fun` at all, i.e.:

```
int main(){
    return fun();
}
```

then the C-compiler zeros the eax-register once again.

Comment: It could be, that the optimizer has a different opimization strategies for c and c++.

Comment: Quirk of the optimiser? What does it do without optimisation?

Comment: How do you get the function names to show in the disassemblies? `objdump -d` is only giving me numbers in the jmp instructions.

Comment: @PSkocik this is not a disassembly, it is asm source output using `gcc -S`.

Comment: @ PSkocik I compile with gcc code.c -S -o assembler.s -O2 and look  directly at the assembly

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In C `int fun();` can take any number of arguments, so it may even be a varargs function. In C++ however it means it takes no arguments.

The x86-64 sysv abi convention demands that the register `AL` must contain the number of SSE registers used when invoking a varargs function. You of course pass no argument, so it is zeroed. For convenience the compiler decided to zero the whole `eax`. Declare your prototype as `int fun(void);` and the `xor` shall disappear.

Comment: Now I stumbled upon this: In ISO C the variadic function has to have a fixed/named argument (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811828/is-it-possible-to-create-a-c-varargs-function-with-no-arguments), so actually compiler should know that `fun` is not a variadic function because there are no fixed parameters. Do you know, why gcc zeroes `al` anyway?

Comment: Because `int fun()` does not provide that information. It could be anything, including `int fun(x, ...)` which is variadic.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something. I think that the compiler deduces the function signature (if there is no parameter specification) from its usage. So if `fun` would be used as `fun(5)` that could mean two things either `fun(int x)` or `fun(int x, ...)`. However `fun()` could mean only `fun(void)`, because `fun(...)` is not valid in ISO C. So from this zeroing `al` should not be mandatory. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Ah yeah, true. I missed you actuall invoked it as `fun()`. Looks like a slight missed optimization then.

Comment: Somehow it is hard to believe, that gcc, clang and icc all missed this optimization..

Comment: This does not explain anything from the point of view of standard C. In C language calling a variadic function that has no previously declared full-blown *prototype* causes undefined behavor. It has been like this since C89/90. For this reason the compiler does not have to assume that a function declared only as `int fun()` has varargs. If it does so, it is a peculiarity of a specific ABI/implementation. A defensive measure, maybe, but a missed optimization as well.

Comment: In fact, a function declaration with an empty parameter type list *never* declares a variadic function.  The compiler does not have to consider calls to the function to make this evaluation.  This follows from the compatibility rules for function types in [paragraph 6.7.6.3/15 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15).  As a practical matter, this makes sense because the calling convention for variadic functions may be different from the convention for non-variadic ones.

Comment: This is probably related to [a Gnu C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Prototypes.html) that allows better interoperability with pre-ANSI code. It can't be dropped now without breaking backwards compatibility (but I guess the Gnu folks care less about that than the Microsoft camp whose terms I'm more accustomed to thinking on).

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is a defensive measure, designed for situations when prototype-less `fun` function happens to actually be a variadic function, as explained by @Jester's answer.

Note though that this explanation does not hold any water from the point of view of standard C language.

Since the beginning of standardized times (C89/90) C language explicitly required all variadic functions to be declared *with prototype* before the point of the call. Calling a non-prototyped variadic function triggers undefined behavior in standard C. So, formally, compilers do not have to accommodate the possibility of `fun` being variadic - if it is, the behavior would be undefined anyway.

Moreover, as @John Bollinger noted in the comments, according to the C standard, a non-prototype `int fun()` declaration actually *precludes* further variadic prototype declarations of `fun`. I.e. a variadic function cannot be legally pre-declared as a `()` function. That would be another reason why the above non-prototype declaration is sufficient for the compiler to assume that `fun` cannot possibly be variadic.

This could actually be a legacy feature, designed to support pre-standard C code, where pre-declaring variadic functions with prototype was not required.

Comment: I think [Cody's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945951/differences-in-the-initialization-of-the-eax-register-when-calling-a-function-in#comment76316514_41946081) in reply to John's is the answer: As an extension to the ISO C rules, the GNU dialect of C doesn't out defining a variadic function after an `int fun();` declaration.